# Impossibility of realizing codimension 1 homology classes by embedded non-orientable hypersurfaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, cohomology, homology

Suppose we have an $n+1$-dimensional compact closed **oriented** manifold $M$ and an $n$-dimensional integral homology class $[\Sigma]\in H_n(M,\mathbb{Z})$ on $M.$ Then is it true that $[\Sigma]$ mod $2$ in $H_n(M,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ **does not** admit an **embedded** **unorientable** representative? Here by $[\Sigma]$ mod $2$, I mean the natural map of tensoring with $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ in the universal coefficient theorem. I do not require the connectedness of the representative.

If one drops the conditions of either codimension 1 or orientability of $M,$ then counterexamples can be found. Immersed counterexamples can also be found. And of course, classes that do not arise from reduction mod 2 of integral classes, evidently have non-orientable representatives only. However, to my best efforts, I could not find a counterexample with all the conditions imposed. I'm aware of Thom's results on representing homology classes with embedded submanifolds. However, to my limited knowledge, they do not address the above question.

The motivation for this question comes from geometric measure theory. Roughly speaking, the question is related to the Lavrentiev gap between minimal area in integral and mod 2 homology. I'm sorry if this question is trivial, as my field is very far from topology. Many thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If $[\Sigma]\in H_{n}(M,\mathbb Z)$ is primitive, its image $[\Sigma] \in H_{n}(M,\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)$ can  *always*  be represented by a non-orientable manifold! Since it is primitive, we may suppose that $\Sigma$ is connected, and since $[\Sigma]\neq 0$ the manifold $M\setminus \Sigma$ is connected and hence there is always an arc in $M$ connecting two points of $\Sigma$ from opposite sides. If you self-connect sum $\Sigma$ along this arc you get a non-orientable representative of the same homology class in $H_{n}(M,\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)$.

Comment: To me it seems like the self connect sum will sometimes be orientable, for instance $S^1 \times * \subset S^1 \times S^1$, is this just an issue that goes away in higher dimensions?

Comment: Yes, we of course suppose $n\geq 2$ and this is enough.

Comment: The issue for $n=2$ is that the self-sum becomes disconnected. But only one of the components can be oriented compatibly with the original curve. In higher dimensions, the self-sum remains connected and there's no hope of orienting it.